# set focus to nested control by selecting the form and vice versa in VB.Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, user-controls

I am trying to understand a concept here. Would be grateful if any solutions provided.

My scenario is where there are 3 nested control on a form. How does the nested child get focus when form containing the controls. In other words what events are fired.

Under next scenario when the inner most child is clicked and now gains focus (correct me if im wrong). Would the parent form gain focus. If yes, then how does this work ? What events are fired .

Any answers would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The control that has keyboard/input ability is the control that would return true for `Focused` and nothing else. A nested child gets focus when the user selects the control or when the `Focus()` method is called programatically.

Honestly, the best way to track the order of events is to create a sample application, add an event handler for the [GotFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.gotfocus%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event and track which control(s) have focus at that time. Since I'm waiting on something to compile, I went ahead and did this.

Example:
My form has a panel with a textbox and a panel with a second textbox on it. All 5 controls have `GotFocus` handled by the same method (`ControlGotFocus`), runs it through a recursive method to check for focus and list the data in `TextBox1`. Panelx did not generate the GotFocus event, nor did Form4, which might be due to when the handler was added. TextBoxx always generated the event correctly, and always listed one and only one control as having focus.

```
    public Form4()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.GotFocus += ControlGotFocus;
        this.panel1.GotFocus += ControlGotFocus;
        this.panel2.GotFocus += ControlGotFocus;
        this.panel3.GotFocus += ControlGotFocus;
        this.textBox3.GotFocus += ControlGotFocus;
        this.textBox2.GotFocus += ControlGotFocus;
    }

    void ControlGotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.textBox1.Text = string.Format("{0} generated the focus event",((Control)sender).Name);
        CheckForFocus(this);
    }

    private void CheckForFocus(Control c)
    {
        foreach (Control item in c.Controls)
        {
            if (item.Focused)
            {
                this.textBox1.Text += string.Format("{0}{1} has focus.", Environment.NewLine, item.Name);
            }
            if (item.HasChildren && item.ContainsFocus)
            {
                CheckForFocus(item);    
            }
        }
    }
```